# Writing down an arbitrary curve in a formal way

Tags: polynomials, summation, notation

I want to write down a curve, which I define as the set of points $x,y\in\mathbb{F}$ (a field) such that $f(x,y)=0$, but I write it as the polynomial $f$ and call $f$ the curve. So I would like to write down a curve of degree $n$ in a formal way, like:
\begin{equation*}
    f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_i x^i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\beta_{i} x^i y^{n-i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n}\gamma_i y^i
\end{equation*}
where $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i$ are the function's *coefficients* in $\mathbb{F}$, the field over which we defined $f$, and the summations should be read as taking all possible cross terms of $x$ and $y$.

My main question is: is it possible to write these three summations in a shorter way such that it describes all possible cross terms (all combinations of powers) and all powers of $x$ and $y$ in a formal way? I.e. without explaining what the sums mean, but it has to speak for itself. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all degree-$n$ terms as well as lower-order terms:
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{\substack{i+j\le n \\ i,j\ge 0}}\alpha_{i,j} \;x^i y^j.$$
If you want it to be homogeneous of degree $n$:
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{\substack{i+j = n \\ i,j\ge 0}}\alpha_{i,j} \;x^i y^j.$$
(If you want the TeX commands for these, right-click them, then "Show Math As" -> "TeX Commands".)

Comment: This first summation is the one I will use, thank you (also for the LaTeX-tip, I always clicked "edit" and copied).